# Clearcase uncheckout Issue

Tags: clearcase

I am having an issue with ClearCase when checkin/uncheckout:

```
Error undoing checkout D:\cc_views\test_cvob\test.cpp

No permission to perform operation uncheckout
Must be one of Object creator , element owner, vob owner,memeber of clearcase group

Unable to cancel checkout for D:\cc_views\test_cvob\test.cpp
```

Note: I'm able to uncheckout/checkin other files in the view

How would you troubleshoot this error message?

Comment: Check the value of the environment variable `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` both for yourself and the other user who is able to checkout the file.

Answer (score 1):

The first way to troubleshoot that kind of error message is by having a look to the rights associated with the version and the file element (with a traling '`@@`'):

```
cleartool descr -l test.cpp
cleartool descr -l test.cpp@@
```

It can be sometime linked to an update issue. Try:

```
cleartool update -overwrite test.cpp
```

Comment: The permissions are default to clearcase

-r--r--r-- 1 user groupname

Note: Another Normal user is able to checkout/undocheckout/checkin the same file

The configuration controller is unable to checkin the file(who has full access to that file).

Could you please let me know what could be issue

"Error undoing checkout D:\cc_views\test_cvob\test.cpp"

Comment: @harish you can edit your question and add the comment in: easier for you to format it and more visible for everybody. Don't forget to delete your previous answer (which was not an answer)